# How to make dotted and bold lines in the same plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a list and i want to plot the list in such a way that for certain range of x axis the lines are dotted while for other range it is solid.
e.g.:

```
y=[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100]
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

i did this:

```
if i range(4,8):
   plt.plot(x,y,marker='D')
else :
   plt.plot(x,y,'--')
plt.show()
```

but this doesnot work.

can someone help?

Comment: I think this plot and code will answer the OP: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKhNq.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes but same color as blue. to show that it is the same line.

Comment: `plt.plot(xb, yb, 'tab:blue', marker='D')`

Answer (score 1):

Slice the data into 3 intervals

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

m, n = 4, 8

x1, x2, x3 = x[:m+1], x[m:n+1], x[n:]
y1, y2, y3 = y[:m+1], y[m:n+1], y[n:]

ax.plot(x1, y1, color='red', linestyle='solid', marker='D')
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='blue', linestyle='dashed')
ax.plot(x3, y3, color='red', linestyle='solid', marker='D')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the same colours for the whole line:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1, y1 = x[:4], y[:4]
x2, y2 = x[3:8], y[3:8]
x3, y3 = x[7:], y[7:]

ax.plot(x1, y1, marker='D', color='b')
ax.plot(x2, y2, '--', color='b')
ax.plot(x3, y3, marker='D', color='b')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line characteristics based on the value of `x`:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

- Make arrays of the lists;

  ```
   y = np.array([11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100])
   x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  ```
- make a boolean array based on your condition(s);

  ```
   dashed = np.logical_or(x<4,x>=8)
  ```
- use the boolean array to filter the data when you plot.

  ```
   plt.plot(x[~dashed],y[~dashed],color='blue',marker='D')
   plt.plot(x[dashed],y[dashed],color='blue',ls='--')
  ```